# Persist request result with RxJava, Retrofit2 and Realm (async)

Tags: android, multithreading, realm, retrofit2

I'm trying to connect to an api, download some data and save them to my local Realm database. To connect to the api I use Retrofit2, returning an Observable object. I'm having problem doing it asynchronously, because Realm obviously tell me that I can't use the same realm object on different thread

Here is my code (not working)

```
new ServiceFactory(getContext()).createRetrofitService(PatientService.class)
            .getPatientsList(token)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnTerminate(() ->
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                })
            )
            .map(PatientsList::getData)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .subscribe(this::updatePatientCard);
}
```

And this is the updatePatientCard method, that throws me the exception
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`

```
private void updatePatientCard(Patient patient){
        String indirizzoResidenza = patient.getResidenza().getIndirizzo().getIndirizzo() + " - " + patient.getResidenza().getIndirizzo().getNcivico() + " - " + patient.getResidenza().getIndirizzo().getProvincia();
        boolean privato = patient.getTipoassistenza().contains("privato");
        PatientCardView card = new PatientCardView(patient.getGuid(), patient.getUniqueKey(), patient.getNome(), patient.getCognome(), patient.getDatan(), patient.getTelefono1(), indirizzoResidenza, patient.getSesso(), privato, patient.isScaduto(), patient.getPhoto());
        patientsList.add(card);
        rvAdapter.animateTo(patientsList);
}
```

The method animateTo simpy add the element to the correct position of the list

If i use the `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` the application freeze while on the `subscribe` step so I cannot use it

Comment: I cannot tell from the above code where you are actually switching threads? You subscribeOn should cause everything to run on `Schedulers.newThread()` as far as I can tell? How are you handling the Realm inside `getPatientsList(token)` ? But one work-around could be to use `realm.copyFromRealm()` to get an in-memory representation of the data.